# c# udpClient sent packets don't exist the router

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, networking

using the following code:

```
UdpClient Sender = new UdpClient();

        try
        {
            Sender.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgOut), msgOut.Length, ip);
        }
```

i am trying to send back a reply to the previous request to the  same ip/port.
while working on the same computer,
it would only work if i customize the values to localhost, as it would not even work when i state my own computer IP in the NAT.

2 facts about it:

1) Same ip/port values work perfectly fine on my c++ version of it. (even across the globe) with the next code:

```
sockaddr_in si_custom;
int s_custom;
//create socket
if ((s_custom = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    //socket fail
    return false;
}

//setup address structure
memset((char *)&si_custom, 0, sizeof(si_custom));
si_custom.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_custom.sin_port = htons(stoi(port));
si_custom.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
//send the message
if (sendto(s, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_custom, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(s_custom);
    return false;
}
closesocket(s_custom);
return true;
```

2) after enabling close to anything remotely relative in the firewall,
my wireshark packet sniffer tells me that my packets DO leave my computer perfectly normal.

I'm trying to figure out, why would a c# udpClient class behave differently than my c++ Udp code in the sense that my router refuses to pass the first one and agrees to pass the latter one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The router do not care where the packets come from (C# or C++). There must be some difference between the two packets. You should test this without NAT.

Comment: what kind of tests do you want me to provide? both of the packets contain same information, same ip and same port. furthermore, i was testing using the same application "Packet Sender" which sends custom packets, and i was receiving packets back on 2 occasions: c++ application, c# localhost ip. and not receiving when using c# on a non localhost ip

Comment: Have you eliminated ipv4 vs ipv6 defaults and also have you checked if your clients use different network interfaces by default

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the UdpClient Sender object with my own Ip:port solved the problem

```
UdpClient Sender = new UdpClient( new IPEndPoint(MyIP,MyPort));
```